# Spring default behavior for lazy-init

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I am beginner to spring, ESP Inversion of control. I was puzzled understanding the difference between the following

```
 <bean id="demo" class="Demo" lazy-init="false"/>
 <bean id="demo" class="Demo" lazy-init="true"/>
 <bean id="demo" class="Demo" lazy-init="default"/>
```

To my understanding : lazy-init=false creates the bean at the startup and lazy-init=true doesn't create a bean at the startup rather creates the bean upon request for a particular bean.
Correct me here, If my interpretation is wrong.

what exactly the default behavior of lazy-init is? How would it instantiate?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The default behaviour is false:

> By default, ApplicationContext implementations eagerly create and
>   configure all singleton beans as part of the initialization process.
>   Generally, this pre-instantiation is desirable, because errors in the
>   configuration or surrounding environment are discovered immediately,
>   as opposed to hours or even days later. When this behavior is not
>   desirable, you can prevent pre-instantiation of a singleton bean by
>   marking the bean definition as lazy-initialized. A lazy-initialized
>   bean tells the IoC container to create a bean instance when it is
>   first requested, rather than at startup.

[I suggest reading up](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lazy-init)

Comment: GWT4Ever: If the default behavior is false, why would one has to specify lazy-init="false" despite they can use lazy-init="default" right? Why two seperate values false, default if their behavior is same?

Comment: This is answered by Zagyi, it's all in the link too.

Comment: updated documentation is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-dependency-resolution)

Comment: I faced this issue due to self injection (needed for spring retry as the method being retried is not the one called by others). @ SpyBean  obviously fails if self injection fields are not marked @ Lazy.

Answer (score 26):

For those coming here and are using Java config you can set the Bean to lazy-init using annotations like this:

**In the configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
// @Lazy - For all Beans to load lazily
public class AppConf {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Demo demo() {
        return new Demo();
    }
}
```

**For component scanning and auto-wiring:**

```
@Component
@Lazy
public class Demo {
    ....
    ....
}

@Component
public class B {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy // If this is not here, Demo will still get eagerly instantiated to satisfy this request.
    private Demo demo;

    .......
 }
```

Answer (score 22):

The `lazy-init="default"` setting on a **bean** only refers to what is set by the `default-lazy-init` attribute of the enclosing **beans** element. The implicit default value of `default-lazy-init` is `false`.

If there is no `lazy-init` attribute specified on a bean, it's always eagerly instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

lazy-init is the attribute of bean. The values of lazy-init can be true and false. **If lazy-init is true**, then that bean will be initialized when a request is made to bean. This bean will not be initialized when the spring container is initialized 
and 
**if lazy-init is false** then the bean will be initialized with the spring container initialization.

Comment: One can set this for all beans in a file: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... **default-lazy-init="true"** >

Answer (score 2):

When we use **lazy-init="default"** as an attribute in  element, the container picks up the value specified by **default-lazy-init="true|false"** attribute of  element and uses it as lazy-init="true|false".

If default-lazy-init attribute is not present in  element than lazy-init="default" in  element will behave as if lazy-init-"false".

Comment: One can set this for all beans in a file: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... **default-lazy-init="true"** >