# How can I set the default behavior of lazy init in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lazy-initialization

I am working on my first **Spring Boot** application and I have the following problem.

I want to set the that for default all beans are lazy loaded. I know that I can add the `@Lazy` to all my `@Component` beans but I want that for default all beans are setted at lazy...

In **Spring Boot** I don't have an XML configuration file or a configuration class but I only have an `application.properties` configuration file.

So, how can I set that the default behavior for all the bean is lazy=true

Comment: not 100% sure to close as duplicate but may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092898/spring-default-behavior-for-lazy-init

Comment: Add a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that sets the `LazyInit` property of all bean definitions to lazy. You might want to exclude everything that is marked as an `INFRASTRUCTURE` bean. Or simply place `@Lazy` on the main application class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok, I placed the Lazy annotation on my main application and it works fine. I think that use a BeanFactoryPostProcessor is too much at this time. But for personal culture: when is better use the BeanFactoryPostProcessor way? If you write your previous comment as a response I will happy to accept your answer :-)

Comment: I think programmatically choosing when to adopt LazyInit would be one reason to opt for a BeanFactoryPostProcessor. E.g. for some tests it might be easier to have LazyInit.

Answer (score 7):

To implement a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that sets lazy initialization by default (which can be required if you are e.g. defining some of the beans dynamically, outside of your `@Configuration` class(es)), the following approach worked for me:

```
@Component
public class LazyBeansFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory( ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory ) throws BeansException {
        for ( String name : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames() ) {
            beanFactory.getBeanDefinition( name ).setLazyInit( true );
        }
    }
}
```

This essentially puts the `@Lazy` annotation on all your `@Component` and `@Service`s. You might want to invent a mechanism to annotate classes with `@Eager` if you go this route, or just hardwire a list in the `LazyBeansFactoryPostProcessor` above.

#### Further reading

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html

Answer (score 5):

Since the version 2.2.2.RELEASE of spring-boot you can use the property below in your application.properties file

```
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

for further reading and a good example please refer to

```
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-lazy-initialization
https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/14/lazy-initialization-in-spring-boot-2-2
```