# Whats is the order dependency injection in spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a question regarding spring dependency injection.
 I need to know whether dependency gets injected in the order in which it has been declared in the XML or 
 there is no order as such.

Example :

```
<bean id="empBean" class="com.test.EmployeeBean">
      <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
       <property name="empAddress" ref="empAddress" />
    </bean>
```

Can we guarantee that always `jdbcTemplate` will be initialized before `empName`? Please help

Comment: No because there is no dependecy between them. BTW `empName` is only a proeprty no bean

Comment: No you cannot. Next to that you shouldn't write code that is dependent on the order things are injected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that these will be injected in any particular order, and you should design your beans such that it doesn't matter -- which is easy to achieve.

So this class is bad code, because its state after bean-creation will differ depending on the order Spring happens to inject:

```
public class BadClass {
    private String foo = "";
    private String foobar = "";

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.foobar = foo + bar;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return foobar;
    }
}
```

Because:

```
 BadClass c = new BadClass(); 
 c.setFoo("foo");
 c.setBar("bar"); 
 return c.toString()`
```

... returns `"foobar"`.

```
 BadClass c = new BadClass(); 
 c.setBar("bar"); 
 c.setFoo("foo");
 return c.toString()`
```

... returns `"bar"`.

Many people think it's best practice to use constructor injection, in which case all the injections will occur in one invocation of the constructor.

```
public class BetterClass {
    private String foo = "";
    private String foobar = "";

    public BetterClass(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.foobar = foo + bar;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return foobar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @slim for confiming

Answer (score 2):

Spring container will traverse the **DAG** (directed acyclic graph) of dependencies and will validate the configuration as much as possible without creating instances of the beans. The exceptions here are **singleton-scoped** and **pre-instanciated** beans, which are created on container creation. You can modify this behavior by adding `lazy-init="true"`property to the bean definition.

Only when the bean is requested in your code, it will get actually created created with all of its dependencies created first (and their dependencies if so needed) traversing the dependencies graph (**DAG**) all the way to the deepest dependencies.

Another case is when beans are defined later with the exact same name. These override the beans defined earlier - so if you have mocks for some of the beans, just define it after the core application beans have been loaded up.

You can add also add property `depends-on="list,of,comma,separated,beanIDs"` to your bean config to guide the container, when some dependencies are not explicit.

When configuring using annotated classes, you can also add `@Order(N)` where lower `N`s get higher priority order used mostly to influence the order of beans being added to a collection, where order matters.

Comment: The default for lazy bean initialization is false: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092898/spring-default-behavior-for-lazy-init -- but you are going beyond answering the question OP asked here.